# Comparison: x == a is true, x == b is true, but a == b is false

Tags: javascript, compare, equals

I have the following javascript code:

```
        console.log("Line: 89");
        console.log(products[i]['barcodes'][j]);
        console.log(barcode);
        console.log(barcode == products[i]['barcodes'][j]);
        console.log(barcode == 888);
        console.log(products[i]['barcodes'][j] == 888);
        console.log(888 == 888);
```

And I'm seeing the following output in the console

```
Line: 89
888
888
false
true
true
true
```

How is it remotely possible that `barcode == products[i]['barcodes'][j]` evaluates to false? How am I supposed to compare these two values?

Comment: What's `console.log(typeof products[i]['barcodes'][j])`?

Comment: you should provide a little bit more code

Comment: I'm guessing 888 are strings, and that there's a space somewhere, only explanation as to why non-strict comparison to a number would work for both, but not comparing them directly.

Comment: Yep, seems most probable. The other chance is that's a single-element array... then again, logging it would have shown it. So spaces should be the key indeed. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
var a = '888';
var b = '888    ';
console.log(a); // 888
console.log(b); // 888
console.log(a == b); // false
console.log(a == 888); // true
console.log(b == 888); // true
```

When you compare `a` and `b`, they are both strings - and are compared directly, without any typecast. So whitespace at the end of `b` does matter here.

However, when you compare both `a` and `b` to *number* 888, the strings stored in these variables are first converted to a number (where the trailing whitespace at the end of `'888 '` is ignored) before being compared.

Comment: I don't know... I think `b = [888]`

Comment: `console.log([888]); // [888]`

Comment: console.log([888] == 888) // it was a joke

Comment: Yup, running barcode = barcode.trim(); fixed the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well, since we don't know what either of those two variables are we can't say. However we can guess that they are not both integers.

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a
>   number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if
>   possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is
>   converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then
>   JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands
>   refer to the same object in memory.

Comment: Actually, we can get a little bit more refined - at lease one value is not a number.

Comment: I'd say at least both values is not a number, as non-strict comparison would work if at least one was a number.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript types can be flaky, and most likely the types are different. You'll have to do something to equalize the types such as

```
parseInt(barcode) == parseInt(products[i]['barcodes'][j])
```

Comment: Ref. [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/x11.html#x11.9.3) - it can lead to surprises, but is well-defined.